# New HP laptop Unable to use Ubuntu 20.04, 21.04

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, hp, 21.04

I am a long time Ubuntu user and recently purchased an HP Pavilion laptop. When using Live Boot, both 20.04 and 21.04 give bizarre resolution and the display is hard to read due to insanely magnified UI.

I decided to install 20.04 and tried doing so. But it resulted in GRUB only coming before Windows 10 (pre installed ) and no Ubuntu even though I successfully installed it from the Live session.

Now I have 21.04 and 20.04 in VirtualBox inside Windows 10. Both have this magnified screen resolution and no WiFi issue. But when I install the Guest Addition CD image through VirtualBox, 21.04 resolution becomes normal, but no change in 20.04.

Is the laptop too new for current versions of Ubuntu ? How can I make Ubuntu work on it normally ? Thanks.

Edit 1:

Fedora 34 live session works fine. I have the same issue with Linux Mint and other Ubuntu based distros.

Edit 2 :

Model no : HP Pavilion 15.6 inch Gaming Laptop PC 15-ec2000 (2P6B3AV)

Video card: onboard Radeon for Ryzen 5 5600H + 4GB Nvidia GEFORCE GTX 1650

WiFi adapter is not detected at all

Edit 3:

Settings has no entry for WiFi

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117M
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:76 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:ffe0000000-ffefffffff memory:fff0000000-fff1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc57ffff
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166a
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166b
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166c
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166d
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166e
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166f
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1670
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1671
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c6)
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
06:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
06:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Comment: The video may be. You never said what video card it has.

Comment: @David onboard Radeon for Ryzen 5 5600H + 4GB Nvidia GEFORCE GTX 1650

Comment: If the geforce is removable I would and see if still have issues.

Comment: I am not sure. It is well packed. Even the battery is not visible to remove. Thanks

Comment: Look in BIOS can it be disabled?

Comment: with all respect. I want to use my laptop as-is. Not kill 1650. I need it for Blender. Thanks.

Comment: Not killing it trying to figure out the problem, good luck

Comment: Could you update your question to include: (1) the model of the HP notebook (2) the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `sudo lspci` (3) a little more info about "no WiFi issue"? You will need to use the Live USB for the second question, as running it in a VirtualBox VM will not offer accurate information about your hardware. With this, it may be possible to provide a specific answer to resolve the compatibility issues.

Comment: @matigo added 1&3 to OP, will add 2 soon. thanks.

Comment: @matigo added all details. Please check, thanks.

Comment: You can fist try using discrete graphics while installation and then update drivers and stuff in ubuntu itself

Comment: just mu 2 cents: the gtx1650 works well with both opensource and proprietary drivers. The onboard graphics might be the problem.

Comment: The wifi adapter and video card should not be detected by a VM Guest. That's expected behavior. The Guest should detect only the generic pseudo-hardware that the Host provides. The Guest has no idea that it's "wired" networking is actually using a wireless connection, and that it's "generic" video is actually being processed by other hardware entirely. Keep the VM Guest problems separate from the Live-on-bare-metal problems. I think the two issues on two hardware platforms might be better as up to four separate questions to avoid confusion.

Comment: @user535733 I have no WiFi entry in Settings issue with Live session as well.

Comment: Precisely. They are likely *separate* problems. On bare metal, that might have a variety of causes. In a VM Guest, it's expected behavior because the Host handles networking and presents the Guest only with a virtual connection.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what to do next. Thanks.